# Simple Mysqli Select query

Tags: php, mysqli

So im trying to to post some data from database in wordpress ,i conect to the database normaly but it wont get any data from it. I have no idea what am i doing wrong.Here is the code

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root123";
$dbname = "MyDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully"."</br>";

$sql = "SELECT event_name FROM wp_em_events";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name :".$row["event_name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Usually people end up failing to locate the problem, because they aren't trying to find it, or are hiding it. use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` while debugging and use `mysqli_error()` to debug queries, to find out whether or not there is a problem with the query

Comment: Have you tried adding your database name to the connection? `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: Yeah $dbname did the trick,tnx for your time guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the database name from your connection.
Change this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

to

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: Bullseye,tnx a lot dude

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've connected to the Database correctly, but you've not specified what table to use. The line:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

Should be:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $tablename);
```